# Nodejs request another attribute other than name from the selected field

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Nodejs and express and I am trying to add multiple values from an input field to the database.

This is my form:

```
form(method='post',action='/form',enctype='multipart/form-data')
.form-check
    label First Question 
    input.form-check-input(name='first', type='radio', id="radio1", value="3" data="option1")
    label.form-check-label(for="radio1") 1
    input.form-check-input(name='first', type='radio', id="radio2", value="10" data="option2")
    label.form-check-label(for="radio2") 2
    input.form-check-input(name='first', type='radio', id="radio3", value="5" data="option3")
    label.form-check-label(for="radio3") 3
    input.form-check-input(name='first', type='radio', id="radio4", value="7" data="option4")
    label.form-check-label(for="radio4") 4
```

In the router file I can successfully capture the value of the selected input radio with `req.body.first` but I would like to also grab the data info to store it on the database along with the value, something like `req.body.first.data`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `data` value to the form data before submitting.

**index.pug**

```
script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js')

form(action='/form',method='post')
    label First Question
    input.form-check-input(name='first', type='radio', id="radio1", value="3" data="option1")
    label.form-check-label(for="radio1") 1
    input.form-check-input(name='first', type='radio', id="radio2", value="10" data="option2")
    label.form-check-label(for="radio2") 2
    input.form-check-input(name='first', type='radio', id="radio3", value="5" data="option3")
    label.form-check-label(for="radio3") 3
    input.form-check-input(name='first', type='radio', id="radio4", value="7" data="option4")
    label.form-check-label(for="radio4") 4
    input(type='submit', value='Submit')

    script.
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('form').submit(function (e) {
          var $selectedEle = $('input[name=first]:checked');
          var data = {
            data: $selectedEle.attr('data')
          };
          data[$selectedEle.attr('name')] = $selectedEle.attr("value");

          $.post({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/form',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (res) {
              console.log('res from server', res);
            }
          });

          return false;// prevent default form submit

        });
      })
```

**app.js**

```
app.get('/form', function (req, res) {
  return res.render('o'); // your pug file
}).post('/form', function (req, res) {

  let formData = req.body;
  console.log('name', formData.first);
  console.log('data', formData.data);

  return res.status(200).send(formData);
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I spent ours trying to figure this out thinking i could access it from the back end without any extra code on the front end. Thanks.